# Wordpress: I wanted to use Add rewrite rule multiple times for multiple CPT in my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, functions, rewrite-rules

The below code is not working. I wanted to use `add_rewrite_rule` wordpress function for multiple post types but it works if i use it once.

I want some one who can make this code work.

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
            add_rewrite_tag('%organization-post%', '([^/]+)', 'organization-post=');
            add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?gb-organization-post=$matches[2]', 'top');
            
            add_rewrite_tag('%course%', '([^/]+)');
            add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?gb-course=$matches[2]', 'top');
            
            
            add_rewrite_tag('%news%', '([^/]+)');
            add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?gb-news=$matches[2]', 'top');
            
            //flush_rewrite_rules();
            
        }
        
        add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );
        
        
        add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
            $query_vars[] = 'organization-post';
            $query_vars[] = 'course';
            $query_vars[] = 'news';
            
            return $query_vars;
        } );
        
        
        function my_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
            $post_id = $post->ID;
            if( ($post->post_type != 'gb-organization-post' && $post->post_type != 'gb-course' && $post->post_type != 'gb-news' ) || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))){
                return $permalink;
            }
        
            $parent = $post->post_parent;
            $parent_post = get_post( $parent );
            
            if($post->post_type == 'gb-organization-post' && $parent_post->post_name != ''){
                $tab_name = get_post_meta($post_id,'gb_tab_name', true);
                $permalink = str_replace('%organization-post%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);
            }
            
            if($post->post_type == 'gb-course' && $parent_post->post_name != ''){
                $tab_name = get_post_meta($post_id,'gb_tab_name', true);
                $permalink = str_replace('%course%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);
            }
            
            if($post->post_type == 'gb-news' && $parent_post->post_name != ''){
                $tab_name = get_post_meta($post_id,'gb_tab_name', true);
                $permalink = str_replace('%news%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);
            }
            
            return $permalink;
            
        }
        add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

Here is My Register Post types Code

```
if ( !function_exists('gb_add_organization_post_types') ) {
    function gb_add_organization_post_types() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Organizations', 'Post type general name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Organization', 'Post type singular name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'Organizations', 'Admin Menu text', 'gb-organization' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Organization', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Organization', 'gb-organization' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Organization', 'gb-organization' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Organization', 'gb-organization' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Organization', 'gb-organization' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Organizations', 'gb-organization' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Organizations', 'gb-organization' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Organizations:', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No organizations found.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No organizations found in Trash.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'featured_image'        => _x( 'Organization Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'archives'              => _x( 'Organization archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into organization', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this organization', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter organizations list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Organizations list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list'            => _x( 'Organizations list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
        );
     
        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'organization' ),
            'taxonomies'         => array('post_tag','category'),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => true,
            'menu_position'      => 200,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-businessman',
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        );
     
        register_post_type( 'gb-organization', $args );
        
        //Organization Posts
        
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Organization Posts', 'Post type general name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Organization Post', 'Post type singular name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'Organization Posts', 'Admin Menu text', 'gb-organization' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Organization Post', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Organization Post', 'gb-organization' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Organization Post', 'gb-organization' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Organization Post', 'gb-organization' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Organization Post', 'gb-organization' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Organization Posts', 'gb-organization' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Organization Posts', 'gb-organization' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Organization Posts:', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No organizations found.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No organizations found in Trash.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'featured_image'        => _x( 'Organization Post Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'archives'              => _x( 'Organization Post archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into organization', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this organization', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter organizations list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Organization Posts list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list'            => _x( 'Organization Posts list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
        );
     
        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => '%organization-post%' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'taxonomies'         => array('post_tag','category'),
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => 200,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-list-view',
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        );
     
        register_post_type( 'gb-organization-post', $args );
        
        //Caurses
        
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Courses', 'Post type general name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Course', 'Post type singular name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'Courses', 'Admin Menu text', 'gb-organization' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Course', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Course', 'gb-organization' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Course', 'gb-organization' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Course', 'gb-organization' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Course', 'gb-organization' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Courses', 'gb-organization' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Courses', 'gb-organization' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Courses:', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No courses found.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No courses found in Trash.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'featured_image'        => _x( 'Course Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'archives'              => _x( 'Course archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into course', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this course', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter courses list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Courses list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list'            => _x( 'Courses list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
        );
     
        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => '%course%' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'taxonomies'         => array('post_tag','category'),
            'menu_position'      => 200,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        );
     
        register_post_type( 'gb-course', $args );
        
        //News
        
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'News', 'Post type general name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'News', 'Post type singular name', 'gb-organization' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'News', 'Admin Menu text', 'gb-organization' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'News', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New News', 'gb-organization' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New News', 'gb-organization' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New News', 'gb-organization' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit News', 'gb-organization' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View News', 'gb-organization' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All News', 'gb-organization' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search News', 'gb-organization' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent News:', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'No newss found.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No newss found in Trash.', 'gb-organization' ),
            'featured_image'        => _x( 'News Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'gb-organization' ),
            'archives'              => _x( 'News archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into news', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this news', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter newss list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'News list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
            'items_list'            => _x( 'News list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'gb-organization' ),
        );
     
        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => '%news%' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'taxonomies'         => array('post_tag','category'),
            'menu_position'      => 200,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-megaphone',
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        );
     
        register_post_type( 'gb-news', $args );
        
    }

}


add_action( 'init', 'gb_add_organization_post_types' );
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It works once because your rewrite's RegEx pattern is the same for all the post types: `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?` - but that's going to clash with the default rewrite rules in WordPress, e.g. for Pages (post type `page`). And I can figure out what you're trying to do, but you see, your post types need a *unique* rewrite base like `organization` as in `https://example.com/organization/<post slug>`. So why not use a unique base, e.g. use `'slug' => 'organization'` for your `gb-organization-post` CPT?

Comment: Actually its a client requirement not to use any slug like `course` or `news`. Is there any solution to replace post type slugs to `''`?

Comment: Well.. yes (but it's complicated) and no (I do not recommend that). But, why don't you try harder to persuade your client to just use a unique rewrite slug? Tell them it's required so that WordPress doesn't have to go through a hard time in determining what kind of query is it for the requested URL? And also to avoid *conflicts* with other permalinks. But if they insist, then my suggestion is: use the default `post` post type and register your CPTs as custom taxonomies instead, then assign them to the `post` post type.

Comment: So for example, for posts that should have been the `gb-organization-post` CPT, assign the posts to the terms in the `gb-organization-post` taxonomy.